# Finding the following definite and indefinite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I want to calculate the integral 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e ^{ \sin t}\, dt.$$
Can we find a primitive function for $f(t) = e ^{\sin t}$?

Comment: I don't think so. Try to express your definite integral with the [Modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and the [Modified Struve functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedStruveFunction.html)

Answer (score 3):

For $\int e^{\sin t}~dt$ ,

$\int e^{\sin t}~dt$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}t}{(2n)!}dt+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}t}{(2n+1)!}dt$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}t}{(2n)!}\right)dt+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}t}{(2n+1)!}dt$

For $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}t~dt=\dfrac{(2n)!t}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

For $n$ is any non-negative integer,

$\int\sin^{2n+1}t~dt$

$=-\int\sin^{2n}t~d(\cos t)$

$=-\int(1-\cos^2t)^n~d(\cos t)$

$=-\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}t~d(\cos t)$

$=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}t}{k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n}t}{(2n)!}\right)dt+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^{2n+1}t}{(2n+1)!}dt$

$=t+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{t}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}t}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{t}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}t}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore$ For $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\sin t}~dt$ ,

$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\sin t}~dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{t}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}t\cos t}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!\cos^{2k+1}t}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}$

Answer (score 0):

No, this one is among the functions that do not admit primitives expressible as a composition of elementary functions.

The definite integral, though, can still be computed, through other means than the Leibniz-Newton theorem. Nevertheless, the result is ugly, since it is expressed with the aid of special functions, so just forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

We recall the following Jacobi-Anger expansion ([DLMF 10.35.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.35)):

$$e^{z\sin t}=I_0(z) + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k+1}(z)\sin((2k+1)t)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k}(z)\cos(2kt)$$

Integrating both sides from $t=0$ to $\pi/2$:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{z\sin t}\,dt 
&= \frac{\pi}{2}I_0(z)+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k+1}(z)\frac{1+\sin k\pi}{2k+1}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k}(z)\frac{\sin \pi k}{2k}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}I_0(z)+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k+1}(z)\frac{1}{2k+1}
\end{align}

There's a few ways we could deal with this infinite sum. First, we can expand the modified Bessel functions in powers of $z$ and confirm agreement with the infinite sums found previously. Second, if we're satisfied with numerical results, we may note that when $z=1$ this alternating sum converges rapidly: To five decimals, the first five partial sums are
$$1.98873,\;3.11905,\;3.10427,\;3.10438 , \; 3.10438 $$
which already has converged to the desired precision.

Comment: There's apparently one last approach: According to WolframAlpha, the integral can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}I_0(z)+\frac{\pi}{2}L_0(z)$ where $L_0(z)$ is the modified Struve function of order zero. So this suggests that the infinite sum over modified Bessel functions is equivalent to said Struve function. But I've been unable to validate this.