# Expansion of a modified Struve function in terms of modified Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions, bessel-functions

The Wolfram functions site includes (without reference) the identity ([source](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/StruveL/06/04/0001/))

$$L_0(z)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{I_{2k+1}(z)}{2k+1}$$
where $L_0(z)$ is the modified Struve function of order zero and $I_n(z)$ is the $n$th modified Bessel function of the second kind. But from my work in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3985369/137524), I think this is incorrect as written and should include $(-1)^k$, i.e., it should be alternating. Can someone provide a reference to either result or a direct proof of such?

Comment: There is a very similar identity for the ordinary Struve/Bessel functions: https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/StruveH/06/04/. However, this one seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.2.E2, http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.4.E21 and http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27.E6, we have
$$
\mathbf{L}_0 (z) =  - \mathrm{i}\mathbf{H}_0 (\mathrm{i}z) =  - \mathrm{i}\frac{4}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{J_{2k + 1} (\mathrm{i}z)}}{{2k + 1}}}  = \frac{4}{\pi }\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{I_{2k + 1} (z)}}{{2k + 1}}} .
$$

Comment: So essentially the WolframFunctions site has the correct version of this identity for the standard Bessel functions, but didn't properly convert this into the modified form.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. I recommend the DLMF as a standard reference about special functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof. We recall the Jacobi-Anger expansion
$$e^{z \sin \theta}=I_0(z)+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k+1}(z)\sin((2k+1)\theta)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k I_{2k}(z)\cos(2k\theta).$$
Evaluating the first $\theta$-derivative at $\theta=0$, we obtain the identity

$$z=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(e^{z\sin \theta}\right)_{\theta=0}
=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (2k+1)I_{2k+1}(z).$$

We now recall that the modified Bessel function $I_n(z)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$x^2 I_n''(x)+x I_n'(x) -(x^2+n^2)I_n(x)=0.$$ As such, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi}z
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (2k+1)I_{2k+1}(z)\\
&=(x^2 D_x^2 +x D_x -x^2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi}(-1)^k (2k+1)^{-1}I_{2k+1}(z)
\end{align}
It follows that the sum
$$y(z):=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (2k+1)^{-1}I_{2k+1}(z)$$
is a solution of the inhomogeneous Bessel equation $$x^2 y''(x)+xy'(x)+x^2 y(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}x.$$ Since all odd-integer modified Bessel functions vanish at zero, it follows that $y$ also vanishes at zero. We now note that the zeroth modified Struve function $L_0(z)$ is *defined* as the unique solution of the above inhomogeneous Bessel equation which vanishes at $z=0$. Therefore we conclude that indeed

$$L_0(z)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{I_{2k+1}(z)}{2k+1}.$$